# Database design will not support entry of products.

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have the database design below:

[table design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR9UG.png)

basically, I need to be able to input products that have the following columns:

**id, area, category, name**

The problem is that if I create the database to the spec in the image above, then wouldn't that still cause repeats in the table catalogue? which would be against the normal forms.

Also it means that the data in catalogue would just be numbers aka references to the other tables. Is there a solution to this issue? as I imagine any catalog site that has a db back-end would have the same issue.

Here is an example that is the same issue just different sinorio if it helps:

I have a product catalog that sells laptops and TVs, do I make a table that has the type of device? because that would look like this:

```
id    -    name    -    type    -    etc

1     -    acerP   -   laptop   -    null
1     -    acerP   -   laptop   -    null
1     -    acerP   -   TV       -    null
```

Notice how 'laptop' could get repeated 100s of times, normally you would create a new table that has just:

```
u_id    -    type

101     -    laptop
102     -    TV
```

Then simply join then in the query, but then you would have in the device table:

```
 id    -    name    -    type    -    etc

1     -    acerP   -     101     -    null
1     -    acerP   -     101     -    null
1     -    acerP   -     102     -    null
```

but now you are repeating the number references.

Am I missing something here, or is this normal?

Comment: Please better describe your current structure. It looks like your catalogue currently holds "machines" only, is this correct? How is `log_table` relevant in your question?

Comment: Yeah, basically the catalogue is used to store the individual items. In the catalogue table are references to 'manufacturing_area', 'manufacturing_category', and 'machine'. This was done so there is flexibility in the database. The log_table is relevant as that references the catalogue cata_id. The question really is should i have just 1 table that holds all of the catalogue items, or split it as i have?

Comment: So your "catalogue" table is meant to contain all the different products that you sell. Among these, there is one category of products that happens to be of type "machine". Now you want your "catalogue" to be able to store other types of products. Am I correct so far? Sorry for asking the same question twice, but this is important.

Comment: Also, I must be missing something in your example. What is the meaning of product "acerP" being both a laptop (twice?!) and a TV?

Comment: Not exactly, the machine table simply has names of machines that exist in the entire catalog. The manufacturing_area just holds areas (aka packing, oven etc) and the manufacturing_category would be 'oven, cooler' etc.

Comment: yeah, in the example I forgot to change the name column, Imagine they are different. Cheers.

Comment: A foreign key can occur more than once in a column without necessarily being an instance of "harmful redundancy".  If the foreign key is meaningless and immutable, you won't have any update anomalies.  If the name "laptop" might be changed to "portable" at some future time, you are better off with the normalized model than with the other one.

Comment: Ahh okay, that would make a lot of sense. I really just needed someone like yourself to validate that what I'm doing isn't too ridiculous. I'd imagine a noSQL db would be better suited but unfortunately the provider I'm using only supports mySQL Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is norma, only foreign keys would be repeated in your proposed structure, which is allowed by the [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form):

> First normal form enforces these criteria:
>    - Eliminate repeating **groups** in individual tables.
>   ...

*Groups* means a combination of columns. The same `category` may appear more than once in `catalogue`, but not, for example the couple (`category`, `area`).